# Bootstrap Datepicker calendar does not hide when you tab through

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Okay, I reviewed the posts that where like my issue, but still can't solve the problem.  The datepicker calendar will not hide if you tab through.  Prior developers coded footer page with the following and we are using the most current version of bootstap-datepicker.js.

I can't find a solution that works.  Can someone help?

```
//data picker
$('#dob').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    fill();
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#dpd1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
}); 

$('#dpd2').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#birthday').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
}); 

$('#sdate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#edate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#esdate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
}); 

$('#eedate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#start_date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#end_date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: do you have that project on jsfiddle?

Comment: not familiar with jsfiddle.  I'll check it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related with datepicker config, because default works fine (tested with datepicker 1.3.0).

Also simplify the code, add all related input fields class `.datepicker`:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    switch (ev.target.id) {
        case 'dob':
            fill();
            break;
    }

    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: I'll try restructuring the code like you presented, but I still think I will run into the same issue.  The datepicker function is still based on the "change" event, and I don't know enough to add code that if not change event occurs and field is no longer on focus it should hide the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $('.dtpicker').datepicker().on('keydown', function(ev){
        if(ev.keyCode === 9){ //tab
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        }
    });
```